# C++ initializing a variable and assigning with std::cin

Tags: c++, cin

This might be a bit stupid question, but I have failed to find any kind of answer for it anywhere else. I am writing codes in C++ (atleast 11 I think) and have to use:

```
int N;
cin >> N;
```

My question is if there is an elegant way to write it as a one line of command? I already know that I can just remove the linebreaks and just put them on one line, but that wouldn't let me use it in a oneliner loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) myVector.push_back();
```

Comment: write a function?

Comment: _but that wouldn't let me use it in a oneliner loop_ So, don't? What's with such a fascination of one-liner loops? Put brackets around the loop body, and you would be able to put as many statements as you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from writing a function, you can put initialization and reading into the header of the `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0, n ; i != 5 && cin >> n ; i++)
    x.push_back(n);
```

This also addresses the problem of having to check the return value of `cin >> n` to ensure that a value has been read properly.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/KyyamK)

Answer (score 6):

An other alternative using algorithms and iterators:

```
std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>{std::cin}
           ,10
           ,std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<int>>{myVector});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your approach is the "best" one, you're pushing back positions (that's so expensive) on a vector and you already know the positions the vector have.
Why don't you just do this:

```
myVector.resize(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) cin >> myVector [i];
```

But, if you can't because you want to use `push_back()`, why don't you just open the braces and write the code inside? What's the matter with that?

Comment: Presumably, OP does not do it because elements `myVector[i]` do not exist when he enters the loop.

Comment: If elements do not exist I don't really know which necessity is to loop over i, that means the position is known. But your approach is correct too and I like it. And yes, keys means braces, sorry.

Comment: Vector index type is `size_t`, with `int` you get warning

Comment: I get the length of the vector in the beginning of the code. I could initialize the vector with placeholder values or push_back() to an empty vector. I am not sure about the efficiency difference between them so I just went with the latter.

Comment: As memory is consecutive imagine that you have a vector of 0 element (where you'll push_back elements) and just after it you have another vector of 100 elements, every push_back on the first vector will move the other vector 1 position each element, which is of cost O(n) where n is the size of the vector. The point is that you can avoid this with placeholders.

Comment: Also, why do you believe `push_back` is expensive? If you precede the loop with a call to `reserve` I would expect the performance hit to be unmeasurable at worst.